# My eclipse says Version 1.8.0_361 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. Version :17or greater is required

Tags: eclipse, installation, failed-installation

I couldn't open the eclipse App

What's the problem where did I gone wrong in the installation process

Comment: The current Eclipse won't run using Java 8. Most Eclipse downloads include a suitable Java 17 - which one did you download? Use the installer at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ or one of the packages at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/